# File.ReadAllLines puts a C: in front of my network path

Tags: vb.net, filepath

I'm trying to use `File.ReadAllLines` to read a .txt file placed on the server where the executable will be running from. But I'm getting the following exception: `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException`

I have access to the server, and I've got other code that has not problem reading a file placed there.

My line of code is the following:

```
Dim familyS() As String = File.ReadAllLines("\
\SERVER_NAME\SHARED_FOLDER\FOLDER\List_Family.txt")
```

And this is the exception:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException : Impossible de trouver une partie du chemin d'accès '**C:**\‪\SERVER_NAME\SHARED_FOLDER\FOLDER\List_Family.txt'.

Why is it putting a `C:` in front of the path ?

Thanks

Comment: This happens if there's only one backslash in front of the servername. Are you sure that the path is correct?

Comment: I posted the code directly from my editor, and i've definitely got 2 backslashes. I also pasted the path from Windows Explorer ...

Comment: The code you posted appears to have a newline character between the first and second "\" character.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i decided to type out the path instead of copying it from an external program and amazingly it works!

If anybody can explain this underneath that would be great.

Comment: Maybe some non printable characters. There are text editors that let you search for these characters. For example Notepad++...